# IMAP error: BAD [PARSE] Syntax error while reading parenthesized list

Tags: perl, imap

i use perl and `Mail::IMAPClient` lib. When i try get header from MAIL.RU using

```
$message_id = $imap->parse_headers($msg,"Message-id")->{"Message-id"}->[0];
```

in debug i can see `BAD [PARSE] Syntax error while reading parenthesized list`
This bag described here [mail.ru bag](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1353800-server-rejects-fetch-body-command-with-space-in-header-specifier-was-incompatible-with-imap-mail-ru)

I can't change lib, because other mail servises keep what is written in RFC. I sent report(probably did not first), but i have not time to wait response. What is best solution to fix this? Send 1 more argument to `parse_headers` if server is MAIL.RU?

Comment: There are MANY alternative ways of getting `Message-Id:`.  What is your program doing? Why do you need `Message-Id:`? The answers may help to choose the best alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a difficult one. The mail.ru server is clearly behaving incorrectly.

My only advice is try to depend only on the most-used bits of the protocol. In this case, try to issue `FETCH ENVELOPE` and `FETCH BODYSTRUCTURE` instead of `FETCH BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (Message-ID)]`. The latter isn't uncommon, not at all, but the former is the most-used bits of the protocol, and so there's reasonable hope that mail.ru may have tested `ENVELOPE` and `BODYSTRUCTURE` enough to catch any bugs that would disturb your client.

Good luck.

Comment: That's just me, or `FETCH ENVELOPE` works slower than `FETCH BODY`?

Comment: Which BODY is that? The older form of BODYSTRUCTURE or an abbreviation for BODY[...]? Either way, ENVELOPE should be as fast as the others on most/all servers.